# How to fix slow boot up time in Kubuntu?

Tags: boot

I recently installed Kubuntu 20.04 on a Samsung Chromebook Plus V2 using the chrx method, and I am getting relatively long boot-up times. After the grub menu, the screen stays blank for about 35-40 seconds before showing the actual Kubuntu logo. How do I fix this?

EDIT 1:

Here is the output of systemd-analyze

[image]

And here is the output of systemd-analyze blame

[image]

And this is systemd-analyze critical-chain

[image]

And also I'm using an eMMC, not an SSD or HDD.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame`? Also, is your disk an SSD or spinning platter HDD?

Comment: `systemd-analyze critcal-chain` is also helpful

Comment: Ok i added them.

Comment: How long does it take to boot to the desktop?

Comment: The time that it takes to go from the login to the desktop is about 6-9 seconds. My issue is the time it takes to go from the grub menu to the Kubuntu logo.